# Is there a way to cancel an animated UITableView/UIScrollView setContentOffset:animated:?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

My app is crashing when my `UITableView` is released whilst animating. The app functions without issue so long as the animation completes. Below is the result of a tap on the `UIButton` which calls `[tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];` and then a lightning quick tap on the `backBarButtonItem` which pops the `UITableViewController`:

```
#0  0x31ec3ebc in objc_msgSend
#1  0x33690248 in -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewAnimationEnded]
#2  0x30defa14 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
#3  0x33690098 in -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:]
#4  0x3368fb7c in -[UIAnimator(Static) _advance:]
...
```

I've never seen a crash on `_scrollViewAnimationEnded` and apparently neither has Google. I have tried calling `[tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];` from the `UITableViewController`'s `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method, but this did not solve the issue.

Any ideas for stopping a `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` in the midst of animating?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This looks like it might be a delegate issue. Do you have a delegate for the table, and, if so, is it dealloc'd when the table is? Try nil'ing out your tableView's delegate before releasing it.

[The tableView is retained by CoreAnimation while it's animating, so that's probably not the problem.]

Comment: I'm not explicitly releasing the table view -- the issue occurred when its controller was popped from view (and if dictated necessary by the navigation controller removed from memory). Still, I think you solved it...ever since assigning and nil'ing the table view's delegate when the view will appear/disappear I have not been able to reproduce this crash. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I saw this crash even when using ARC. Be sure to nil out the table delegates manually!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with you is that you are releasing the datasource array, before you release the tableView. try checking this out too in the dealloc

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you inserted a refresh controller into a table view as a subview (my hint, never do that)...