# Scroll view delegate crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I get a lot of crashes reported in crashlytics referring to UIKit. Specifically scrollView delegates. It looks something like this:

```
-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _delegateScrollViewAnimationEnded]
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
```

There is also other UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _delegate* methods that crash sometimes. I can't reproduce and since it don't specify my app anywhere in the crash log i don't know where this would be. My best guess now is that that this can occur in different places in the app.

Because it's a BAD_ACCESS on a delegate I am thinking it could be that the delegate is deallocated before the actual scrollview or tableview? This could cause a crash even with ARC right? Since delegates are week. The app has many scrollviews/tableviews/collectionviews so manually trying to find the bug by just looking at the code seems like a long shot. One problem with this tho is that the delegate is most often the view controller that owns the scrollview/tableview. In that case could the view controller be deallocated before it's view and that views subviews?
Anyone experienced the same or similar? Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898626/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-an-animated-uitableview-uiscrollview-setcontentoffseta check it

Comment: Thanks Sport, I'm trying out that solution now. It's probably going to be a couple of weeks before i know if it works tho...

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView delegate is not weak, it's pre ARC legacy and uses assign.

Therefore if the delegate is deallocated, it will cause a BAD_ACCESS. Make sure to set the delegate to nil to avoid this.

Good reading on the topic: http://inessential.com/2015/05/27/how_not_to_crash_6_properties_and_acce

Comment: UIScrollView's delegate property has been weak since iOS 2.0.

Comment: That's just not correct. `assign` is not the same thing

Comment: You need to be clearer in your answer then. The property looks like this:
`@property(nullable,nonatomic,weak) id<UIScrollViewDelegate>        delegate;`

Comment: Feel free to edit. This was posted more than a year ago, apple probably changed this with iOS 9? I still believe this answers the question.